# Single SQLAlchemy mapped object resulting in many different instances in memory

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I know that title was convoluted, so I'll try to give a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. Please bear with me for a bit.

I'm working on an option values calculation and portfolio risk analysis server, and I've run into a problem I'm not quite sure how to address when loading my persisted object graph and then accessing some cached properties that I've dynamically added database load.

Say I have the following mapped classes:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Portfolio(Base):
    __tablename__ = "portfolios"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    asset_classes = relationship("AssetClass", backref="portfolios")

class AssetClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = "asset_classes"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    portolio_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("portfolios.id"))
    assets = relationship("Asset", backref="asset_classes")

class Asset(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    asset_class_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("asset_classes.id"))
```

Then I load a Portfolio and do some initialization as follows:

```
session = Session()
# pretend there's only one Portfolio
portfolio = session.query(Portfolio).one()
init_portfolio(portfolio)
while(keep_server_alive):
# session stays open for server life
    gevent.sleep(0)
session.close()


def init_portfolio(p):
    # note that this is a dynamically added property
    portfolio.values_store = ValuesStore()
    for asset_class in p.asset_classes:
        init_asset_class(asset_class)


def init_asset_class(ac):
    for asset in ac.assets:
        init_asset(asset)
```

Once everything is initialized I use a long running gevent thread to process price updates and calculate certain derivative values, as follows:

```
def on_underlying_update(asset, underlying_price):
    # the next line non-deterministically fails with an AttributeError
    values_store = asset.asset_class.portfolio.values_store
    values_store.get_asset_price(asset, underlying_price)
```

These calculations can be quite expensive, so the ValuesStore object has a caching strategy to store the results. On random passes through the on_underlying_update function, I'll get an AttributeError saying that the Portfolio object doesn't have a values_store property.

At first this really confused me, but as I debugged the issue a bit I seemed to find that the child AssetClass objects referring to the same Portfolio might actually be referencing different objects in memory. I came to believe this after using python's id() function to check Portfolio.id's against memory id's during each access. Doing so, I would routinely find that while I might have only ever access one Portfolio.id, I was referencing several different memory addresses depending on which child was doing the accessing.

I know this was long winded, and I appreciate anyone who's stuck with me this far. My question is, is there a way for me to load an entire object graph in to memory once and only once? This ValuesStore object can be expensive from a resources perspective, and I'd prefer to instantiate it as few times as possible.

For reference, I"m using Python 2.7.3, SQLAlchemy 0.8, gevent 1.0rc2, and I'm experiencing the same issue on both Windows 7 and OS X 10.8.

Thanks again.

** edit **

I spent a lot of time going through my code looking for statements that would cause a Portfolio object to be detached from the current session and attached to a new one. I couldn't find anything of the sort. I tried to listen to all sorts of Instance and Session events, and each time, I could see the "new" Portfolio being loaded but it was being loaded by the original Session.

Is it possible that the Portfolio object is being garbage collected? I tried testing this hypothesis by spawning a new Gevent thread to hold onto a strong reference to the Portfolio as follows:

```
def keep_portfolio_alive(p):
    portfolio = p
    while True:
        gevent.sleep(0)
```

This seems to solve the issue. I never see the Session load the portfolio a second time.

** edit 2 **

So I'm not sure, but I believe I've found my problem. When defining the relationships between mapped classes, I actually used attribute_mapped_collections instead of normal lists. When initializing the classes, I would iterate over the child objects like so:

```
for asset_class in portfolio.asset_classes.itervalues():
    # do something
```

Since some of these classes are multiply nested, along the hierarchy there was a class that had been referenced using this copied-iterator, and it then referenced its own child classes using another copied-iterator. My best guess is that the Portfolio class ended up with no strong references between either it and its parent object, or it and any of its child objects. The GC then marked it for collection at some point.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: there seem to be major details missing codewise, as I only see one Session above.  The Session will only instantiate one and exactly one object for a given database identity (that is, table X + primary key Y).   so if you have many copies for a given identity, that implies you have many sessions, or are detaching objects, or something.  Can you provide a simple, fully self-replicating test case ?

Comment: sorry it took me a bit to get back to you. the project is significantly larger in scope than the example, so i spent some time trying to reproduce the error in a smaller but more complete piece of code.